# Gnuplot (Terminal Cairolatex)-set path in \includegraphics

Tags: gnuplot, pdflatex

Terminal Cairolatex generates two files: eps/pdf + tex file.
In the tex file a path to the eps/pdf file is given, it looks normally like this:

```
 \put(0,0){\includegraphics{*.pdf}}%
```

where *.pdf is the defined outputname.

Is there a way to change only the tex file (and not the eps/pdf file) like this (by setting commands in a gnuplot script)

```
\includegraphics{path/*.pdf}
```

that I can define a *path* to the pdf in gnuplot?

I am sure that there exists workarounds with awk and sed, but I would prefer a gnuplot-intern solution.

Comment: No, you cannot set different paths for eps/pdf and the .tex file